# transform cross sectional data to panel data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe looks as:

```
loan id    borrowing_date  principal    maturity_date    maturity_time(years)
01         2013-03-03      1000000      2015-03-03       02
02         2015-07-30      2000000      2017-07-29       02
03         2017-10-03      3000000      2020-10-02       03
```

I want each borrowing date and maturity date to expand quarterly for next 10 years. i.e. it should look like as

```
loan id    borrowing_date  principal    maturity_date    maturity_time(years)
01         2013-03-03      1000000      2015-03-03       02
01         2013-06-03      1000000      2015-06-03       02
01         2013-09-03      1000000      2015-09-03       02
.              .              .              .           .
.              .              .              .           .
01         2023-03-03      1000000      2025-03-03       02
.              .              .              .           .
.              .              .              .           .
03         2017-10-03      3000000      2020-10-02       03
03         2018-01-03      3000000      2021-01-02       03
03         2018-04-03      3000000      2021-04-02       03
.              .              .              .            . 
.              .              .              .            .
03         2027-10-03      3000000      2030-10-02       03
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want 4 quarters for each borrowing date, or just the remaining quarters until Q4 for that borrowing date?  Eg, loan 2 borrowing date is 2015-07-30, so it starts in Q3.  For this row, do you want 2 rows, one for Q3 and one for Q4; or 4 rows, for 2015Q1 through Q4?  Presumably you want to repeat the data present in the other columns for subsequent quarters added?

Comment: each loan should contain 4 quarters for the next 10 years. e.g. loan 1 starts from 2013-03-03 and will end in 2023-03-03. Thus, it contains 40 quarters (4*10). Same for the loan 02 and 03. The principal and maturity time column will remain the same. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `data.table` option making use of `lubridate`

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(df)[, .(
    borrowing_date = seq(as.Date(borrowing_date), as.Date(borrowing_date) %m+% years(10), by = "quarter"),
    principal,
    maturity_date = seq(as.Date(maturity_date), as.Date(maturity_date) %m+% years(10), by = "quarter"),
    maturity_time.years.),
    by = loan.id]
#    loan.id borrowing_date principal maturity_date maturity_time.years.
# 1:       1     2013-03-03   1000000    2015-03-03                    2
# 2:       1     2013-06-03   1000000    2015-06-03                    2
# 3:       1     2013-09-03   1000000    2015-09-03                    2
# 4:       1     2013-12-03   1000000    2015-12-03                    2
# 5:       1     2014-03-03   1000000    2016-03-03                    2
#---
#119:       3     2026-10-03   3000000    2029-10-02                    3
#120:       3     2027-01-03   3000000    2030-01-02                    3
#121:       3     2027-04-03   3000000    2030-04-02                    3
#122:       3     2027-07-03   3000000    2030-07-02                    3
#123:       3     2027-10-03   3000000    2030-10-02                    3
```

Explanation: We use `seq.Date` to generate a sequence of dates `by = "quarter"`, where the final date is the original date plus 10 years (or in `lubridate` syntax `%m+% years(10)`).

Please note that column names have changed (it's generally bad practice in R to have column names with special characters like spaces, commas etc.).

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "'loan id'    borrowing_date  principal    maturity_date    maturity_time(years)
01         2013-03-03      1000000      2015-03-03       02
02         2015-07-30      2000000      2017-07-29       02
03         2017-10-03      3000000      2020-10-02       03", header = T)
```

Comment: I didnt know how to keep the principal and maturity_time similar across all quarter. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You're very welcome @EhtashamBillahMymun; if this answers your question please consider closing the question by setting the green checkmark next to the answer. Thanks.